# How to covert a a 24 hour time to hours and minutes

Tags: python

I have been given a task to find differences between time. I don't have a problem finding how much hours and minutes there are in that time. I am having trouble with subtracting them. when I subtracted 40 it gave me the right difference of minutes for 1305 and 1205 ( doesnt work for 59 101) but it still shows a -1 hour difference. I expect it to show a 10 minute difference for 1255 and a 2 minute for 59.

I know I have to make it so that the program knows 60 minutes for an hour. I've gotten advice to first change the time to minutes then find the difference than change that to hours and minutes but I'm confused on that. I've tried but it messes with the numbers again. If anyone could give advise on taking away the -1 thanks.

```
A = int(input("A departs at: "))
Ahours = A // 100
Aminutes = A % 100

B = int(input("B departs at: "))
Bhours = B // 100
Bminutes = B % 100

differenceH = Bhours - Ahours
differenceM = Bminutes - Aminutes - 40
```

Comment: yeah i get the confusion. 1305 and 1255 are times in 24 hour format so is 50 and 101. I expect it to show me the difference for these like 10 minutes for 1305 and 1255 but for me its saying theres an hour difference when theirs not. Same with 50 and 101 it says i have a 1 hour and 98 difference which is wrong again. Im just wondering how to fix the problem with the hours.

Comment: Maybe you could detail what you expect to happen when you enter 1305 and 1205? (or 59 and 101)
I don't mean simply the result you expect, but also the value of each variable as your program proceeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to convert both times to a number of minutes and compute the difference in terms of minutes, then convert the result back to hours/minutes.

You can convert your HHMM time format from an integer to a number of minutes using `X-X//100*40`.  Then you can do a simple subtraction and convert the result back to HHMM either using `divmod(X,60)` or  `D+D//60*40`

```
numA = int(input("A starts at: "))
numB = int(input("B starts at: "))

numA -= numA//100*40    # 1255 --> 775 minutes since midnight
numB -= numB//100*40    # 1305 --> 785 minutes since midnight

diff = numB - numA

print( diff+diff//60*40, divmod(diff,60) )
```

Sample run:

```
A starts at: 1255
B starts at: 1305
10 (0, 10)         # 10 minutes
```

If you need to go around midnight when numA is greater than numB, simply apply modulo 1440 to the difference.

```
diff = (numB-numA) % 1440
```

...

```
A starts at: 2330    # 1410 minutes since midnight
B starts at: 0145    #  105 minutes since midnight
215 (2, 15)          # 105-1410 = -1305,
                     # -1305 % 1440 = 135
                     # 135 minutes is 2 hours and 15 minutes
```